# Reload iframe once iframe is loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I need to reload (recycling) iframe each time it full loaded

I trying do this with javascript

```
    <iframe id="iframe_your_bids" src="../file.asp">
    </iframe>

    <script> 
    $(document).ready(function() {
    document.getElementById('iframe_your_bids').contentWindow.location.reload();
    });
    </script>
```

But iframe do not reloading

How to reload iframe each time then it fully loaded?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`.load`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) event like so

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#iframe_your_bids').load(function(){
    document.getElementById('iframe_your_bids').contentDocument.location.reload(true);
  });
});
```

```html
<iframe id="iframe_your_bids" src="../file.asp"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#iframe_your_bids').load(function(){
    document.getElementById('iframe_your_bids').contentDocument.location.reload(true);
  });
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ivinraj/xo9z9gps/1/)